# Powershell AES, Decryption is blank... but encryption has a value

Tags: powershell, encryption

Any ideas about why the decryption is empty?  This is a cut and paste from some code on a website thats supposedly works.

Output:

```
This is my message
6CzIwCN0AcVOwffrGs0KZ+YPKbCatw41Ui0FDOIg1fc=
(Nothing here)
```

```
try {
    $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    
    function cipher_makekey {
        
        $AESEncryptionKey     = [System.Byte[]]::new(32)
        $InitializationVector = [System.Byte[]]::new(16)
        
        $RNG = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        $RNG.GetBytes($AESEncryptionKey)        
        $RNG.GetBytes($InitializationVector)
        $RNG.Dispose()
        
        return [PSCustomObject]@{
            Key = $AESEncryptionKey
            IV  = $InitializationVector
        }
    }
    
    function cipher_encrypt {
        param(
        [PSCustomObject]$Key,
        [String]$Text
        )
        
        
        $AESCiper = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AESCryptoServiceProvider
        $AESCiper.Key = $Key.Key
        $AESCiper.IV  = $Key.IV
        
        $UnencryptBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($Text)
        $Encryptor      = $AESCiper.CreateEncryptor()
        $EncrtptedBytes = $Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($UnencryptBytes, 0, $UnencryptedBYtes.Length)
        
        [byte[]]$FullData = $AESCiper.IV + $EncrtptedBytes
        
        $CiperText = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($FullData)
        
        $AESCiper.Dispose()
        
        return $CiperText
    }
    
    function cipher_decrypt {
        param(
        [PSCustomObject]$Key,
        [string]$Text
        )
        
        $AESCipher      = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider
        $AESCipher.Key  = $Key.Key
        $EncryptedBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Text)
        if (-not $EncryptedBytes) {
            throw "Its Null"
        }
        $AESCipher.IV   = $EncryptedBytes[0..15]
        
        $Decryptor      = $AESCipher.CreateDecryptor()

        $UnencryptBytes = $Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($EncryptedBytes, 16, $EncryptedBytes.Length - 16)
        $TextDecoded   = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($UnencryptBytes)
        
        $AESCipher.Dispose()
        return $TextDecoded
    }
    
    function main {
        $Plain1 = "This is my message" 
        $Plain1
        
        $Key    = cipher_makekey

        $Secret = cipher_encrypt -Key $Key -Text $Plain1
        $Secret

        $Plain2 = cipher_decrypt -Key $Key -Text $Secret
        $Plain2
        
    }
    
    main
}
catch {
    throw $_
}
```

Comment: General advice: don't put everything in a `try` block if you're troubleshooting.

Comment: try block doesn't hurt if you rethrow...

Answer (score -4):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    
function cipher_salt {
    param(
        [int32]$NumBytes
    )
    $randbytes = [System.Byte[]]::new($NumBytes)
    
    $RNG = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider
    $RNG.GetBytes($randbytes)        
    $RNG.Dispose()
    return $randbytes
}

function cipher_makekey {
    
    $Key = cipher_salt -NumBytes 32

    return [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $Key
    }
}

function cipher_encrypt {
    param(
        [PSCustomObject]$Key,
        [string]$Text
    )
    
#NOTE Create a Key and IV:
#$RNG = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider

$AESEncryptionKey     = $Key.Key

#[System.Byte[]]::new(32) #NOTE: 32 Bytes (256-bit Key)
#$RNG.GetBytes($AESEncryptionKey)

$InitializationVector = cipher_salt -NumBytes 16
#[System.Byte[]]::new(16) #NOTE: 16 Bytes (128-bit IV)
#$RNG.GetBytes($InitializationVector)

#NOTE: Create a AES Crypto Provider:
$AESCipher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider

#NOTE: Add the Key and IV to the Cipher
$AESCipher.Key        = $AESEncryptionKey
$AESCipher.IV         = $InitializationVector

#NOTE: Set the secret:
$MySecretText         = $Text

#NOTE: Encrypt data with AES:
$UnencryptedBytes     = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($MySecretText)
$Encryptor            = $AESCipher.CreateEncryptor()
$EncryptedBytes       = $Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock($UnencryptedBytes, 0, $UnencryptedBytes.Length)

#NOTE: Save the IV information with the data:
[byte[]] $FullData    = $AESCipher.IV + $EncryptedBytes

# NOTE: Transforms the data to string format
$CipherText           = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($FullData)

#NOTE: Cleanup the Cipher and KeyGenerator
$AESCipher.Dispose()
#$RNG.Dispose()
return $CipherText

}

function cipher_decrypt {
    param(
        [PSCustomObject]$Key,
        [string]$Text
    )

#NOTE: Decrypt data with AES:
$AESCipher = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider

#NOTE: Set the AES Key:
$AESCipher.Key        = $Key.Key

#NOTE: Get the encrypted string:
$EncryptedBytes       = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Text)

#Note: Get the IV data for AES:
$AESCipher.IV  = $EncryptedBytes[0..15]

#NOTE: Decrypt the with AES:
$Decryptor            = $AESCipher.CreateDecryptor();
$UnencryptedBytes     = $Decryptor.TransformFinalBlock($EncryptedBytes, 16, $EncryptedBytes.Length - 16)

#NOTE: Transform the data from byte array to string
$MySecretText         = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($UnencryptedBytes)

$AESCipher.Dispose()

write-host "HI"
#NOTE: Get the secret:
$MySecretText
}

$Plain1 = "This is my super secret 123"
$Key    = cipher_makekey
$Secret = cipher_encrypt -Key $Key -Text $Plain1
$PLain2 = cipher_decrypt -Key $Key -Text $Secret

#$Key

write-host "Plain1: $Plain1"
write-host "Secret: $Secret"
write-host "Plain2: $Plain2"
```